# SVM output to probabilistic affiliation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, svm

How can I convert the svm output for multiple class classification(one vs one approach) to probabilistic values? Meaning that I want to have a probability for a tested element to be in each available class.

Thanks!

Comment: I you can find more details by comparing the SVM and other techniques such as PLSA.

Comment: Can you give me more details about what it is?

Comment: Mathematica 10 has built-in machine learning, including SVM, and its straightforward to get the probablity.

Comment: Can you explain me how that is straightforward? What does this software use?